# What does spawn mean in this sentence?

Tags: computing

> When referring to Linux or Unix, init is a program loaded by the
>   kernel that **spawns** all other processes and typically uses PID 1.

What does *spawn* mean in this sentence? Thank you.

Comment: To spawn: . To produce or give rise to, ( generate). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spawn

Comment: Or to invoke certain processes and elements, in case you were  from a programming background.

Comment: Yeah that means better @Invoker .

Comment: This is a question for Stack Overflow or Super User, not this exchange.

Comment: It seems you are right @Hot Licks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *spawn* is being used as a transitive verb:

> : to cause (something) to develop or begin : to produce or create (something)
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spawn)</sub>

In UNIX operating systems, this is accomplished by self-replication, and then the clone (the one that does not have the same process id as the original, usually called the child) allows itself to be usurped by a different program (executable).